# Why am I getting a "Missing Application-Name manifest attribute" error when it's in my manifest?

Tags: java, jnlp

JRE 8U20, I'm getting "Missing Application-Name manifest attribute" when running my application via JNLP.  I haven't looked at the console in awhile, so I don't know when this started happening again.  Back awhile ago I had similar issues due to manifest issues, but I don't know why it started again as my manifest attributes seem to be in place:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: http://mystuff.mydomain.net
Application-Name: MyApp
```

Is there something wrong with my manifest?

Comment: is your manifest in a folder META-INF ? is it named MANIFEST.MF ? Is it readable by the tomcat user ?

Comment: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.  Tomcat is uninvolved.  This is a JNLP project launched from IIS.

Comment: sorry, it was a reflex reaction. tomcat is so often involved with java ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstart appears to need a blank line at the end of the manifest.  Adding a carriage return to the end of my manifest data resolved the issue.